# How to transfer stream Data Frame to S3 on the basis of size of stream data accumulated?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Right now, my code is like -

```
dataFrame.writeStream().trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerTime))
```

which triggers the transfer after every "triggerTime" interval.

Now, I want the transfer to trigger only when I have much of data accumulated. 
Trigger doesn't seem to provide any option for size based trigger.

Does anyone know about this?